# R: Splitting dataset by pre-determined values

Tags: r, split, dataset

I have data that looks like this (but larger):

```
   Pos    Value
     0 66.81967
     1 66.36885
     2 65.79508
     3 65.27049
     4 64.88525
     5 64.97541
     6 65.39344
     7 65.99181
     8 66.63115
     9 66.95901
    10 66.89344
    11 66.44262
    12 65.90984
    13 65.49181
    14 65.35246
```

I have already determined the maxima and saved the position values of each to a vector like so:

```
 9  19  30  42  56  69  80  92 107 118 130 143 154 164 176 188 199 211
 222 234 245
```

I now want to split the data based on the value of the maxima, so for the sample data I'd want to split the dataset into the values for Positions 0->9 and into the values for Positions 10-15, and save each of these sub-sets into vectors of their own.

I'm new to R (and coding) and was wondering how to best go about this.

Comment: Why `10-15`? Isn't it `10-19`?

Comment: I said 10-15 because I only provided the data up until value 15 (or rather, I thought I had. I notice now I only provided up to 14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is `dat` and your maxima values are in a vector `maxima`, you might use

```
split(dat, cut(dat$Pos, breaks = maxima, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

For your example data frame:

```
dat <- 
structure(list(Pos = 0:14, Value = c(66.81967, 66.36885, 65.79508, 
65.27049, 64.88525, 64.97541, 65.39344, 65.99181, 66.63115, 66.95901, 
66.89344, 66.44262, 65.90984, 65.49181, 65.35246)), .Names = c("Pos", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

and the first few values of your maxima in the range:

```
maxima <- c(0, 10, 19)
```

my code gives you a list of data frames

```
#$`[0,10]`
#   Pos    Value
#1    0 66.81967
#2    1 66.36885
#3    2 65.79508
#4    3 65.27049
#5    4 64.88525
#6    5 64.97541
#7    6 65.39344
#8    7 65.99181
#9    8 66.63115
#10   9 66.95901
#11  10 66.89344
#
#$`(10,19]`
#   Pos    Value
#12  11 66.44262
#13  12 65.90984
#14  13 65.49181
#15  14 65.35246
```

---

If you don't want data frames, but just `Value`, use

```
split(dat$Value, cut(dat$Pos, breaks = maxima, include.lowest = TRUE))

#$`[0,10]`
# [1] 66.81967 66.36885 65.79508 65.27049 64.88525 64.97541 65.39344 65.99181
# [9] 66.63115 66.95901 66.89344
#
#$`(10,19]`
# [1] 66.44262 65.90984 65.49181 65.35246
```

---

> Thanks! How would I go about saving these as separate data frames/sets (not sure on the correct terminology) so that I can then fit them individually?

How about

```
lst <- split(dat, cut(dat$Pos, breaks = maxima, include.lowest = TRUE))
dir <- getwd()
lapply(seq_len(length(lst)),
       function (i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file = paste0(dir,"/",names(lst[i]), ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
```

This will save each data frame into a `.csv` file under directory `dir`. I have used `getwd()` to test the code; you may change it to a specific folder.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about saving these as separate data frames/sets (not sure on the correct terminology) so that I can then fit them individually?

Comment: Thank you again! I accepted the answer. One last thing though – when I run that code, it only saves the sections from the second partition onward, i.e. the first partition (0-10) is not saved as a .csv. Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is the best approach, but I would work with a list and use a for loop like this (untested):

```
maxpos <- c(9, 19, 30)
ans <- list()
prev <- 1
for (i in seq.int(length(maxpos))) {
    ans[[i]] <- dataset[seq(prev, maxpos[i]),]
    prev <- maxpos[i+1]
}
ans[[length(maxpos)+1]] <- dataset[seq(maxpos[length[maxpos]]+1,nrow(dataset)),]
```